# How do i Consume WCF Data Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

i have created a wcf service but i have used 3 projects for it; 
1) ServiceLibrary (WCF library) 
2) Web 
3) ConsoleTestClient 
my `ServiceLibrary` app.config file looks like this;

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MrDAStoreJobs.ServiceLibrary.AdvertisementService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="basic" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" 
                  contract="MrDAStoreJobs.ServiceLibrary.Interface.IAdvertisementService" />
        <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          address="mex" />

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:13758/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel> <br />
```

Now, to host this library, i have done the following settings in my `Web.Config` file of the `Web` Project. 
The svc file name is `WcfDataService1.svc`

```
    public class WcfDataService1 : DataService<AdvertisementService>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }
    }
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MrDAStoreJobs.ServiceLibrary.AdvertisementService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="basic" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" 
                  contract="MrDAStoreJobs.ServiceLibrary.Interface.IAdvertisementService" />
        <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          address="mex" />

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:13758/WcfDataService1.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Now, when i test this service using directly (ServiceLibrary project) using WCF test client, i see the following and works everything great;
[image] 
The issue is when i try to run my `Web` project(which i use as a host for wcf service). And then go to the console test client and want to add reference using add reference. I don't see my `Get` and `Set` methods (like test client)
[image]
**Why i don't see my IAdvertisementService interface and the methods** 
**Do i have to deploy this to actuall IIS?**

Comment: AdvertisementService is not a WCF Service, its a WCF DATA Service. Completely different things. You want to consume WCF Data Services with [DataServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

To develop a service using ASP.NET, we must add the WebService attribute to the class and WebMethodAttribute to any of the class methods.

Example

```
[WebService] 
 public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService 
  { 
  [WebMethod] 
  public string Test(string strMsg) 
  { 
      return strMsg; 
  } 
 }
```

To develop a service in WCF, we will write the following code:

```
[ServiceContract] 
public interface ITest 
{ 
   [OperationContract] 
   string ShowMessage(string strMsg); 
 } 


public class Service : ITest 
   { 
       public string ShowMessage(string strMsg) 
       { 
          return strMsg; 
       } 
   }
```

The ServiceContractAttribute specifies that an interface defines a WCF service contract, 
OperationContract attribute indicates which of the methods of the interface defines the operations of the service contract.

A class that implements the service contract is referred to as a service type in WCF.

**Hosting the Service**

ASP.NET web services are compiled into a class library assembly and a service file with an extension .asmx will have the code for the service. The service file is copied into the root of the ASP.NET application and Assembly will be copied to the bin directory. The application is accessible using URL of the service file.

WCF Service can be hosted within IIS or WindowsActivationService.

Compile the service type into a class library
Copy the service file with an extension .SVC into a virtual directory and assembly into bin sub directory of the virtual directory.
Copy the web.config file into the virtual directory.

**Client Development**

Clients for the ASP.NET Web services are generated using the command-line tool WSDL.EXE.

WCF uses the ServiceMetadata tool (svcutil.exe) to generate the client for the service.

For more detail goto this link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/139787/What-s-the-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-Services

Answer (score 1):

**Previous Post Removed:**

---

**Update:**

The Microsoft Developer Network actually covers this in great detail, some of the resources they provide are:

- [Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx)
- [Tutorial From Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/135490/Advanced-using-OData-in-NET-WCF-Data-Services)

There are also several books that my solve this particular endeavor.  Since someone stated that providing links to solve this issue doesn't truly answer your question I'll attempt to.

1. Inside Visual Studio click *File*, then proceed to *New Project*.
2. In the dialog expand *Visual C#*, Select *Web* and *ASP.NET Web Forms Application*.
3. Give your project a name of your choice `NorthwindWeb`.

At this point you've created a project; due to the complexity of a *Service* overlooking a tiny detail can be catastrophic in the outcome.  That is why I'm starting from scratch.

In my example I'll link it to a *Database*.  So I'll add a *Ado.Net Entity Data Model*.  I'll name my model: `NorthwindModel`.  I'm also going to generate based upon an existing *Database*.  So up at this point just follow the Visual Studio Wizard. Choose your *Database Objects* within those tables, then Finish.

The important part, building my `Data Service`.

1. Project *Add New Item*.
2. Select *Web* and choose *WCF Data Service*.
3. Put a name, `NorthwindCustomer`- Then *Add*.

Locate the first `Todo:` Comment and remove the code then put:

```
public class DemonDbCustomer : DataService<demonDbEntities>
```

Then find the comments in the `InitializeService` Event Handler:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
```

At this point hit **CTRL +  F5** to run the service.  The browser will open and the XML Schema for the service will generate.  In the *Address Bar* type in *Customers* at the end of the URL for `NorthwindCustomers.svc` and hit *Enter*.

** Sometimes Internet Explorer will mess this up, so additional troubleshooting may be required. **

Now we will create our Client Portion.

1. *Add* a *New Project*
2. Select *Windows Forms Application*
3. Name the file of your choice, `NorthwindClient` then click *Ok*.
4. In the *Solution Explorer* select the `NorthwindClient Project` and *Set As Startup Project*.
5. Right Click on Project: *Add Service Reference* Click *Discover*.

At this point your URL for `NorthwindCustomers Service` will appear in that *Address* field.  This is generated from that `.svc` file.

Now we have to provide data binding to our service.

1. On the *Data Menu* we want to *Show Data Sources*.
2. *Add New Data Source*
3. Choose the type of `Data Source` and follow the Wizard (Click Object).
4. Select the Object you wish to bind.

Now at this point you just need to create a `User Interface`. To do so just simply drag your `Customers Node` from your `Data Sources` to the `Form`.

- `DataGridView`
- `BindingSource`
- `BindingNavigation`

They are all added automatically.  Then simply double click your `Form` and add the following to your `Form1_Load Event Handler`.

```
ServiceReference1.northwindModel.northwindEntities proxy = new 
     ServiceReference1.northwindModel.northwindEntities(new
         Uri("http://localhost:53397/NorthwindCustomers.svc/"));

// As you see it pointed to our SVC file, because that includes our Address, Binding, Contract information.

this.customersBindingSource.DataSource = proxy.Customers;
```

Now in your *Solution Explorer* right click that `NorthwindCustomers.svc` and click *View In Browser*.  The XML Schema will be added, so you just copy that URL from the *Address Bar*. Then replace the `Uri` with the one you just copied.

Run your application and you've down the following:

- Host
- Client
- Service
- Consumed

That is how to consume a **WCF Data Service** the article that has even more detail is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668184.aspx):

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: thanks for ur recommendation. But do hosting wcf service on iis express works?

Comment: Well, I believe Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, and Windows Server 2012 all utilize IIS: 6, 7, 7.5 / 8 I believe by nature.  But if you only have IIS Express, then yes it will work as long as IIS is configured to handle those Service Request.

Comment: i have already watched some of the books from packtpub and wrox