# How to call WCF service from C++

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, dll, cross-platform

I have a WCF Service. I need to call it from C++.

The solution can be using C# dll to call WCF and calling it from the C++ code. 
Or C++ dll directly calling WCF Remote Service.

**EDIT :** I have tried importing the C# dll into C++ file with the help of the follwing Code Project [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18240/COM-Interop-the-Hard-Way). But In my C++ file I cant import like this :

```
#import "tlbfile.tlb" raw_interfaces_only named_guids
```

> ERROR  Cannot open source file tldfile.tlh

**EDIT 2 :** I have decided to use VC++. And made a C# dll to call the Web Service. But cant refer the dll in MFC Application.

Im running on VS 2012.

Comment: I have a C# project which communicates with a PHP project via WCF service. I have the C# project with the service and in PHP I call the wsdl. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254251/how-do-i-consume-wcf-service  Maybe this will help you out.
The webservice generates a WSDL, and then you need to call the WSDL in your C++ project.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686452/create-wcf-service-for-unmanaged-c-clients

Comment: @user1467261 Yes.The answer is really good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some of the above mentioned that the WCF exposes WSDL. Which is platform independent.
You can use any of the ways you mentioned.

1: Create C# client as library(dll) and use that dll in C++ code using interoperability. But this is tedious process as Interoperability is tedious.

2: Create direct C++ client:

```
 A. Create C++ proxy class from WSDL file
 B. Use that proxy class in your Code for communicating with Server. You will have to maintain Channel opening and closing.
```

3: Use third party libraries to handle communication channel. One of the best library is POCO.
[Poco Library for C++](http://pocoproject.org/)

Comment: How do you make a call to a `WCF` service using `POCO`?

Comment: Please note that I have found this link to be helpful: https://pocoproject.org/pro/docs/00152-RemotingNGTutorialPart3.html